LAN Networking - Local DNS Name not Working in Windows Browser
I have a home server (running Ubuntu, which I named "lenovo") that runs a couple of HTTP servers. These HTTP servers are accessible to other clients on my home LAN. They are always accessible to clients when using the static IP of the home server. They are also always accessible to clients when using the Ubuntu computer name (with .local added): "http://lenovo.local". However, the server is not always accessible from some clients when using the local DNS name which I assigned it via my Unifi Console: I assigned the Ubuntu machine the "Local DNS Record" of "lenovo.redacted.duckdns.org". (I did this after finding advice online that said not to use ".local" and instead to use a real DNS name). I actually am using "redacted.duckdns.org" to point to my public IP -- but I am using "redacted" here instead of my actual duckdns reservation, obviously.
The problem:
When trying to access "http://lenovo.redacted.duckdns.org", it ALWAYS works when using curl on the commandline (and nslookup on the name also always works as expected). It also works on MacOS. BUT on the Windows 11 computers, and when using a web browser to view the URL, it very often results in "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" (or similar -- the exact error evades me as the issue is not occurring right now). Note that the issue is only seen on Windows 11 using a browser such as Chrome or Edge. On the same Windows 11 machines on the command line, it always works (curl and nslookup). In browsers on Windows, it sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't work (as in, reloading over and over will intermittently work then not work, flapping on and off). The IP address "http://192.168.1.200" and the Ubuntu-assigned "http://lenovo.local" always work as well. It's only the Unifi-assigned DNS name that is causing problems, and only in Windows 11 browsers (Edge and Chrome). What's going on?
I checked windows networking, it says it is using DNS 1.1.1.1 and that it's not encrypted. MacOS is also using the same DNS server.

I’m confused. If you are not using the Unifi device’s DNS server, how would this work at all?

unless your clients are configured to use the local DNS server you set up in Unify, then that server cannot do anything. that it works at all indicates you must have NAT hairpinning enabled, if you can access local services using the public IP while inside the LAN. Not all routers can provide hairpinning without performance and reliability issues. anyway the point of split-horizon dns (which you seem to be attempting) is to have your internal clients served by the local DNS server, not the cloudflare dns at 1.1.1.1

@DanielB I don't know. I'm also confused. I clearly don't know how this stuff is supposed to work -- that's why I'm on here asking questions.

@FrankThomas I'm don't think hairpinning should work -- I don't have port forwarding setup -- yet. But, I don't really know what I'm doing, hence the networking question.

Based on your comments I did some more work and found out that the DCHP server tells clients which DNS to use -- I've updated the router to use "Auto" DNS. Disconnecting and reconnecting the ethernet cable on my windows machine shows that the DNS IP on the Windows machine is now pointed at the gateway. Hopefully this fixes the issue. It would be nice to know how/why it was working before, but, as long as this fixes the issue, I'll be happy. (Any chance it was [sometimes] working due to mDNS ?)

you'll have to pardon me for thinking external access is part of this, as you registered a public domain to point to your public IP. does your domain name in Unifi match the duckdns.org domain you registered? if so, then pointing the client to use the unifi DNS, which serves a local IP, is the correct fix and should work well for you. I don't know about needing a publicly registered domain if you are not going to host services for the public, but I do agree with avoiding .local, as its generally less reliable (despite your mostly positive experience with it).

I suspect since you're using Chromium browsers (Edge and Chrome), the 1.1.1.1 DNS setting triggers DoH upgrade on the browser which ignores the local DNS resolution. Try disabling that setting explicitly (called either secure/encrypted)

@Martheen that does sound like it might be playing a part in this.... Thank you for that tidbit of info.

@FrankThomas thank you for your thoughts. Domain name in Unifi is set to the default "local". I have not opened these services up to public, but I would like to do that after I get HTTPS (TLS) configured.

So that just makes it all the more confusing. how could you curl to your public IP by using the public DNS name, and get anything but a failure when you haven't forwarded any ports? Also, you should not set up a DNS server for a .local zone. .local is used for UPNP to provide naming for networks that don't have a DNS server. .local names are resolved via Multi-Cast DNS, where instead of asking a DNS server what the IP address is, it sends a multicast message to the whole network asking the system with that name to announce itself.
